# Pop up alert doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, bootstrap-modal, alert

I try to display a pop up alert using modal but the pop up doesn't appear
Here is the code that I have written

```js
function CallService() {
  $.ajax({
    url: '/url,
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "xml",

    success: function(xml, status) {
      $(xml).find('occurrences').each(function() {
        alert("Demande soumise avec succès");
      });
      $(xml).find('errors').each(function() {
        $(this).find("error").each(function() {
          var label = $(this).find('label').text();
          $(document).ready(function() {
            $(".erreur").append("<div class='alert alert-danger' role='alert' style='width=50%'> <strong>" + label + "<strong></div>").modal('show');
          });
        });
      });

    },
  });

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="erreur"></div>
```

Comment: this ? what's this ? please share all code

Comment: You're using `this` where there is no outer scope, so it will refer to the `window`. It's also outside the document.ready handler so you're trying to find elements which don't exist yet.

Comment: you are using bootstrap modal?@fiolafafa

Comment: Take a look at this: https://jsfiddle.net/cr29y1tc/7/ - sure seems to work!

Comment: your fiddle not working properly,please provide working example @RolandRuul

Comment: yeap @SuriyaSubramaniyan

Comment: close quotes in url, url: '/url', @fiolafafa

Comment: see my updated answer to show alert in your success @fiolafafa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

close quotes in url parameter.
Change 
      **url: '/url,**
to
      **url: '/url',**

Try this

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#openme").click(function(){
        $("#myModal").modal();
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<button id="openme" class="btn btn-default">open!</button>
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">modal title </h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p>confirm </p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">no</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">yes</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Updated**

I change your function to open alert popup try this,

```js
function CallService(){
  var label ='your success response';
  var modalContent ='<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">'+
        '<div class="modal-dialog"><div class="modal-content">'+
  '<div class="modal-header">'+
  '<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button><h4 class="modal-title">Alert</h4></div><div class="modal-body">'+
  '<p>'+label+'</p></div></div></div></div>';

          $(".erreur").html(modalContent);
    $("#myModal").modal();
                                                         
              }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="erreur"></div>
<button onclick="CallService()">click me</button>
```